# Android .apk file is not downloading completely from .Net Server. Getting Package Parsing Error in phone

Tags: java, android, .net, web

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class HomePanel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadFile();
    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadFile();
    }
    private void DownloadFile()
    {
        string getPath = "E-MobApps/Sab Recharge.apk";
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(getPath);

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
            System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[1024];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            Response.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

This is my server side code and I am trying to make my android .apk file downloadable on link click. But the file downloaded is 16 kb ie smaller than actual ie. 3.5 MB
What sort of problem it may be. Even my phone memory is enough to save the app

Comment: any errors on the http server log

Comment: No error on server log

Comment: Have you solved this issue. am facing the same  from java server.Please let me know if you have solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
  Response.Flush();
```

inside the **loop** that is reading your stream. So you are writing to the Response.OutputStream and you are cleaning the response in the next line.

Try reading the whole stream to byte[], and do not assign anything in the loop.

When your byte[] is complete, then assign the content to the response.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS i defined MIME type "application/vnd.android.package-archive" for  .apk and In aspx page I put hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your client side (Android) code is working well?

Here's my tested solution in client side:

```
private void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
    try {

        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        conn.connect();

        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(u.openStream(), 8192);

        // output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new  FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        publishDownloadProgress(0);
        toggleDownloadProgressbar(true);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        long total= 0;
        int count;
        while((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            publishDownloadProgress((int) ((total*100) / contentLength));
            output.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        if(IsDebugging)
            Log.e("FileNotFoundException", e + "");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(IsDebugging)
            Log.e("IOException", e + "");
        return;
    }
}
```